# Arrange nested dict items Python

Tags: python, defaultdict

I have written this code and it is fine, but the output of the dict is not what i want. Here is the code:

```
class EbExportCustomer(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    @api.one
    def get_pa_data(self):
        aValues = defaultdict(dict)
        aValues['partner_id'] = self.id
        aValues['name'] = self.name
        aValues['street'] = self.street
        aValues['street2'] = self.street2
        aValues['zip'] = self.zip
        aValues['city'] = self.city
        aValues['country'] = self.country_id.name
        aValues['state'] = self.state_id.name
        aValues['email'] = self.email
        aValues['website'] = self.website
        aValues['phone'] = self.phone
        aValues['mobile'] = self.mobile
        aValues['fax'] = self.fax
        aValues['language'] = self.lang
        aValues['child_ids']['name'] = []
        aValues['child_ids']['function'] = []
        aValues['child_ids']['email'] = []


        if self.child_ids:
            for child in self.child_ids:
                aValues['child_ids']['name'].append(child.name)
                aValues['child_ids']['function'].append(child.function)
                aValues['child_ids']['email'].append(child.email)

        return aValues
```

I am currently using `dicttoxml` and `collections.defaultdict`, The output is this:

```
 <Partner><item>
 <website>http://www.chinaexport.com/</website>
 <city>Shanghai</city>
 <fax>False</fax>
 <name>China Export</name>
 <zip>200000</zip>
 <mobile>False</mobile>
 <country>China</country>
 <street2>False</street2>
 <child_ids>
  <function>
   <item>Marketing Manager</item>
   <item>Senior Consultant</item>
   <item>Order Clerk</item>
   <item>Director</item>
  </function>
 <name>
  <item>Chao Wang</item>
  <item>David Simpson</item>
  <item>Jacob Taylor</item>
  <item>John M. Brown</item>
 </name>
<email><item>chao.wang@chinaexport.example.com</item>      \ <item>david.simpson@epic.example.com</item><item>jacob.taylor@millennium.example.com</item><item>john.brown@epic.example.com</item></email></child_ids><phone>+86 21 6484 5671</phone><state>False</state><street>52 Chop Suey street</street><language>en_US</language><partner_id>9</partner_id><email>chinaexport@yourcompany.example.com</email>
```

But i would need the output for `child_ids` to be like:

```
<child_id>
< function > 
 Marketing
Manager 
</function>
< name >Chao
Wang  </ name >
< email >  chao.wang @ chinaexport.example.com </ email>
</child id>
```

And then another `<child id>` with the fields from all the other child ids.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You want a single list (of dictionaries, probably), rather than three parallel lists.  Something like this:

```
aValues['child_ids'] = []


for child in self.child_ids:
    aValues['child_ids'].append({
        'name': child.name,
        'function': child.function,
        'email': child.email
    })
```

Comment: yep got the output that i needed: <child_ids><item><function>Marketing Manager</function><id>24</id><name>Chao Wang</name><email>chao.wang@chinaexport.example.com</email></item>
Is it possible to change the tag <item> ?

Comment: Assuming that you are using at least version 1.7 of dicttoxml, it looks like you can pass an `item_func` option to the `dicttoxml()` constructor to override the list element's name, based on the list's name.  `item_func=lambda x: x[:-1]`, it would produce `<child_id>...</child_id>` for each of these items.

Comment: How could i remove this the <item> </item> ?<shipping_address><item><city>Fremont</city><zip>94538</zip><street2>False</street2><country_id>235</country_id><street>3661 Station Street</street><country_name>United States</country_name></item></shipping_address>